# Sorting an CTE Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a CTE Recursive query which returns the output as expected, however It would be nice if I can control the sort. For example I would like to sort PARENT nodes by using a custom SORT column in table...and IF POSSIBLE sort the nodes under Parent Categories as well by using a SORT column.

Hete is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a7eb/4)

Please look at sort Column, With Sort output should  be something like this.

```
 Appliances < -- Parent
   Dryers
   Washers
 Toys < -- Parent
 Furniture < -- Parent
```

if sorting on child nodes is NOT possible then its fine, but it would be nice to atleast control the sort for PARENT nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b5e1/8/0) for the latest question/fiddle edit.  Same idea, but one more ISNULL, as I forgot to handle NULL sorts in the recursive part.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS lvl, catcode, catName, parentID,
        CAST(catCode AS VARCHAR(max)) AS Path,
        CAST(isnull(sort,9999) AS VARCHAR(max)) AS SortPath
    FROM categories WHERE parentID =0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.lvl + 1, c.catCode, c.catName, c.parentID,
        p.Path + '_' + CAST(c.catCode AS VARCHAR(max)),
        p.SortPath + '_' + CAST(isnull(c.sort,9999) AS VARCHAR(max))
    FROM categories c
    INNER JOIN cte p ON p.catCode = c.parentID
)
SELECT 
    catCode, 
    catName AS catName, 
    lvl,
    Path,
    parentID
FROM cte 
ORDER BY SortPath
```

Note: A single varchar(max) within a series of string concatenations makes the end result a varchar(max).  A single cast will do.

FYI - for future SQL questions, it would be really great if you could prepare a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) schema, and what query you have thus far.  This allows others to spend minimal time on setup.  It also helps the discussion if you had to expand on the sample or provide what if query variants.

Comment: Have you tried my query? It seems to sort correctly (`by sortpath`).

Comment: Richard, I populated more data into categories table & it seems like your suggested code does not work. here is Fiddle with more data
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5abd8/1

Comment: please note, i added SORT with NULL values (in fiddle above), you can play around with SORT column data to see different results.

Comment: I'm seeing DDL with SORT all set to null. Therefore, you're not actually asking for any specific sort. can you set some up, and show that it doesn't sort according to what you set up?

Comment: ok, lets make it simple, I just want to SORT the parent nodes...so according to this fiddle(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b5e1/1/0), I want Appliances first (then its nodes), Then TOYS, Then Furniture (and its nodes). I specified the SORT value for Appliances, Toys and Furniture...which are 3 PARENT nodes.

Comment: Thanks, there is a minor bug...you will notice "Front Load Washers" is under Dryers, however its a child of Washers. And also French Door Washer should be under Front Load Washers.

Comment: You should really consider putting a SORT value to all records, if you want any predictable sorting. The first CTE in the latest update does that. It also means I can strip the ISNULLs from the other CTEs.

Comment: Richard, last version of my menu is huge  & its impossible to create a manuall SORT entries for all rows (with multiple applications using it).  what if I make SORT column inherit value from ID field, and then use that SORT column for Join in CTE (instead of ID column). This way I can let end users EDIT the Sort column values to control the SORT of nodes.

Comment: I got it to work, trick is AS LONG AS  Parent node's have unique Sort value then it works (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c48cf/1/0).

Comment: Congratulations, I think we have a winner!

Comment: do you agree with my last fiddle? I think that is the ONLY way of doing it....given all PARENTS must have unique sort values.

Comment: That's not the ONLY way. In my answer, I made a unique "sort-id" for each using row_number. It only needs to be unique within the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can find the answer r your question, but I think the whole idea of the question is wrong. Once you got the records ( unsorted ) from DB, you would usually convert them into some kind of object hierarchy. There you can build the hierarchy very quickly without really records need to be sorted.